# How to have auto-complete for SASS classes generated with a mixin

Tags: html, sass, webstorm

I have a mixin that generates the classes for the directions of flex.

This is the snippet:

```
// Generated class
$flex-directions: 'row', 'row-reverse', 'column', 'column-reverse', 'normal';
@each $direction in $flex-directions {
  .flex-#{$direction} {
    @include flex-direction(#{$direction});
  }
}
```

But in my HTML code, WebStorm does not suggest the classes created with mixins.

How I can create an interface of a mixin or another way to have the class auto-complete in WebStorm?

Answer (score 0):

I do'nt know if there is a way to make WebStorm autocomplete the classes from the mixin itself, but but if don't include / parse the build css file WebStorm will read the created classes there and suggest them for auto-completion.